# Machine Learning on Images - Is it a good idea to expand the dataset by creating rotated copies of current dataset images?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have different classes of medical X-ray images, but they are not equal in number. The number of images in each class varies from ten to thousands. If I can't obtain further images in each class, is it a good idea to expand the current dataset by creating rotated copies of the images in the current dataset?

Comment: Why would you want to create copies of images? If you are doing Machine Learning/Deep Learning on images, duplicating example images will not make the algorithm training any better.

Comment: What do you mean by making them equal? Do you mean to make the number of images in each class equal? If you want to just create a copy, what about copy=existing is wrong? Do you also want to bring them all to the same viewing angle?

Comment: @MechtEngineer. So if i have imbalance number of images in each class. (Means total number of images is like 10, 100, 350 , 578 etc in class like elbow, hand, shoulder, neck.) will this be fine.

Comment: @Vahni Yes i want to make number of images equal. say all class should have 500 images. instead of 10, 100, 350, 578. Since they are x-ray images i am thinking to make some little rotation to the existing images. How this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the number of images in each class to be equal? From my limited understanding of training image processing algorithms, the more images you have, the greater the confidence you can have that your algorithm works for a variety of test images. So if you are testing your algorithm on different parts of the body, and you have different numbers of images for each of the parts of the body, then you will end up with different confidence levels for how well your algorithm can perform on different parts of the body (the less training images, the less confident you will be that your algorithm is robust for a variety of input images).

The variety of test images is a key concept. You have proposed rotating images to give your algorithm more variety. This may work, but also may cause issues, as the rotation may create [artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(error))/artificial errors in the data that were never present in the original raw data. This has the potential to train your algorithm incorrectly (it might start to recognise these artifacts as features, when these features will never be present in original, unrotated data).

In summary, my advice would be to find ways of obtaining more images, rather than manipulating your current limited set and potentially training the algorithm incorrectly.

Comment: . Yes might be true what you said. (Artificial errors). I too have limited understanding as i am new in image processing. But obtaining more images is difficult as image data sets was provided by IMAGECLEF.  So its a challenge for us how we can make it balance and work on it, because of its imbalance in nature.  So i am trying out that method.